# I need to make changes to my httpd.conf i cant find it

Tags: httpd.conf

I am attempting to host a second website on my magento platform however this requires me to make some changes to the httpd.conf file on my server. Only problem is i cant find this file anywhere. I'm using centos 6 and in the file system iv tried trying to find and it doesn't seem to exists iv tried finding it using the shell and the c panel file manager.

Is there any chance it could have a different name im so confused.

Help is much appreciated, cheers in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If it's not in /etc/apache2/, go to the /etc directory and try

find . -type f -name "*.conf"

Newer apache has multiple configuration files in a sub directory, so you may actually need a different .conf depending on what you're doing.